# How to input a value that has a unit as "per something"?

Tags: matlab, input

Okay, so my question is if I have a value such as 0.9 micromolar<sup>-1</sup>.sec<sup>-1</sup>. How should I enter this value in the code.

Which one is the correct one?

```
v = 0.9e-6
```

or

```
v = 0.9e6
```

Comment: The "per" part won't effect your units. If it's *micro* then you want `e-6`. `e6` would be for *mega*. The per just means that your units are "molar" but rather "per molar". So instead of "micromolar" you have "per micromolar". This does change the fact that you need `e-6` and not `e6`. BTW, this is not a programming question and you should ask it on [physics.se] rather

Comment: Right now I am not sure about my answer! If you want to have as units molar^-1 sec^-1 then you have actually input `e6`, as `0.9micromolar^-1 sec^-1 = 0.9/(10^-6molar sec) = 0.9 10^6 / (molar sec)`. I had read it wrongly when giving my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your unit is molar, then you should use the first one `v = 0.9e-6`as it is `0.9*10^(-6)` molars.

The second option, however, is 0.9 millions of the unit. However, this is a basic question not very related to the program but about the units you are using.